# getting a value from the array in php

Tags: php

when i say

```
var_dump($this->variables['DEFAULTS_VALUES']);
```

I get the Following array

```
array(1) {
  ["ABE LOB RPT"]=>
  string(8) "BEST2"
}
```

how do i get the value `["ABE BBB CCC"]` from this array
when i say in this way `$this->variables['DEFAULTS_VALUES'][0]`
It says `UNDEFINED OFFSET:  0` .how do i get the value `["ABE BBB CCC"]` from this array

Comment: That's not a value it's a key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting "undefined offset" errors because there's no value at index 0 in that array.  [PHP arrays are actually "ordered maps"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), and what looks like the first value here is actually a key -- `$this->variables['DEFAULTS_VALUES']['ABE LOB RPT']` would give you back 'BEST2'.

If you actually want the keys, the `array_keys` function would give them to you.  Or you could use a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($this->variables['DEFAULTS_VALUES'] as $key => $value)
{
    print "$key: $value<br>\n";
}
```

In your case, the one and only time through the loop would print out "ABE LOB RPT: BEST2".

Answer (score 0):

Your array is [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) you need this:

```
echo $this->variables['DEFAULTS_VALUES']['ABE LOB RPT']; // BEST2
```